# Error while migrating from Laravel tinker console (sqlite)

Tags: laravel

Consider

```
laravel new bug
```

Then adding in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=/home/me/Code/bug/storage/database.sqlite
```

creating database

```
touch /home/me/Code/bug/storage/database.sqlite
```

migrating

```
php artisan migrate && php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Now trying to migrate programmatically in tinker

```
php artisan tinker
>> Artisan::call('migrate');
```

First time resulting in => 0 (as expected ?) But second time:

```
>>> Artisan::call('migrate:fresh')
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 17 database schema has changed (SQL: select * from
>   sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)'
>
> > > Artisan::call('migrate')
> > >       Third time:
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException with
>   message 'There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace.'

Any ideas whats going on here? Can you reproduce?

---

Update using postgres. The second time running Artisan::call('migrate:fresh') I get:

> Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException with
>   message 'There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace.'

---

UPDATE 2: Issue filed here: <s>https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22997</s>
https://github.com/laravel/tinker/issues/37

Comment: Confirming I can reproduce the error. FYI, you seem to have a typo in your database path. In `.env` you have it pointing to `database`, but when you create the file it's pointing instead to the `database` directory. Assuming this is a typo and not your actual steps, as I was able to reproduce while referencing the proper path.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that was a typo while drafting the post. Fixed in edit.

Comment: Have you tried getting it to work using MySQL yet? Worth a try to see if we can narrow it down to a sqlite driver issue or a larger Artisan issue

Comment: have you set  'ATTR_PERSISTENT' => TRUE in your connection config ? and APP_ENV=local ?

Comment: APP_ENV=local - yes, ATTR_PERSISTENT - no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think if this is a laravel bug, but I found your problem:

Calling a non existing command like `Artisan::call('migrate:fresh')` will crash. The reason is a typo: tinker does not accept `fresh`, only `refresh`. Calling the command via tinker will empty the sqllite file so you can't execute any commands until you migrate without tinker.

Here are my steps:

```
php artisan migrate # sqllite file is filled with content
php artisan tinker
> Artisan:call('refresh')
> Artisan::call('fresh') # now the sqllite file is empty
> Artisan::call('migrate') # will crash
php artisan migrate
> Artisan::('refresh') # works
```

so I think it's a tinker bug, not a laravel one. Tinker is doing some kind of snapshot (If you change a Model you have to restart tinker to call it there), maybe the error handling is not implemented is the best way to catch all errors.

Comment: Thanks! Second paragraph, no? \Artisan::call('migrate:refresh') gives the exact same error as \Artisan::call('migrate:fresh'): There are no commands defined in the "migrate" namespace. But yes its tinker related as the commands are working in web.php (where I actually need them).

Comment: Refresh will not work if it crashed before. Only if you have a non empty sqllite file. You have to reset it with a non tinker call, then it should work

Comment: Thanks got it. Moved the issue to the correct repo: laravel/tinker